# IIS virtual directory deploy rewrite

Tags: typescript, iis, deployment, url-rewriting, aurelia

I tried to deploy an aurelia front-end to IIS under virtual directory as http://localhost:8004/test/

However, when it is loading, all css and js bundle can not be load and throw 404 not found like this
http://localhost:8004/assets/css/styles.fbcd976941829d21d019.css

[image: 1]

But if I append prefix test into that url manually on chrome browser then I can load that css like this http://localhost:8004/test/assets/css/styles.fbcd976941829d21d019.css.

I have tried some IIS URL rewrite but still not succeed. Can anyone help me for this please? Thank you

I have tried IIS URL rewrite but it could not load those css and js bundle

Comment: What is the project structure and path you published to IIS? Is it possible that the url itself is wrong? You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the baseUrl value in the webpack.config.js file to match the virtual directory.

Somewhere near the beginning of the webpack.config.js file...

Change

`const baseUrl = '/';`

To

`const baseUrl = '/test/';`